# XCode4 Autosizing Can't Adjust Inside the Box

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I am unable to adjust the autosizing INSIDE the box. How do I adjust or do I have to recreate the view...?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autosizing behavior is how a view's size and position changes relative to it's parent when it's parent changes.  So to adjust inside the box, you'd be adjusting subviews.

Are you saying that view has subviews and you want to adjust their autosizing?  You can just select the subviews and adjust them.

Comment: I'm saying that the ability to adjust for the subviews is unchangeable. Do you notice how the arrows inside the smaller box is partially "greyed" out?

Comment: Or does that mean that the subviews of the main view, the one that is currently selected, override the parent view? Thanks!